# Find answer for data in A in predefined list of answers - VLOOKUP - Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, vlookup, gs-vlookup

I've got a google spreadsheet with a `main sheet` tab. column A contains a bunch of company names, some of which repeat, and are included multiple times. In column B i want to have a predefined unique code for each company. For instance if I had a company name Nike in a10, a14, a21 I would have the same code each time in b10, b14, b21.

I was initially looking at if / else blocks and switch statements (not sure if google spreadsheet can even do them) to accomplish this, but they would become massive and unmanageable as single line pieces of code will involve several hundred company names.

Instead I've setup another tab called `Codes Data` with a predefined list of all of the company names in column A and the code in column B. This list will be added to over time.

What I'm trying to do is have a formula in the `main sheet` column B that will check the value of the corresponding column A cell, find the unique code for that company in the `Codes Data` tab and place that code in column B.

I started using VLOOKUP for this and at first it seemed to work, but now I'm getting inconsistent results (i.e. its outputting `Addidas | am-1121` and `ACMECO RESTAUR | am-1121` where according to the Codes Data sheet it should output `Addidas | ad-5426`).

I've provided an example spreadsheet here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/156Lla5IyLjB-hp7s50jpotC1qcaov9RdFkpUzATe710/edit#gid=458436476

Is VLOOKUP the correct function to be doing this? If so, how can I use it more properly, and if not what would be a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add `FALSE` to your lookup formula, or it won't work:

```
=VLOOKUP(A5, 'Codes Data'!$A:$B, 2, FALSE)
```

Use the Help menu, and choose "Sheets Help", and then type in "vlookup".  You'll get the documentation:

> is_sorted - [OPTIONAL - TRUE by default] - Indicates whether the column to be searched (the first column of the specified range) is sorted.
>
> If is_sorted is TRUE or omitted, the nearest match (less than or equal to the search key) is returned. If all values in the search column are greater than the search key, #N/A is returned.
>
> If is_sorted is set to TRUE or omitted, and the first column of the range is not in sorted order, an incorrect value might be returned.
>
> If is_sorted is FALSE, only an exact match is returned. If there are multiple matching values, the content of the cell corresponding to the first value found is returned, and #N/A is returned if no such value is found.

Comment: Thanks @sandy Good - Whats the purpose of is_sorted - is it to allow you to use VLOOKUP over data that is not 100% identical or is it to make the script faster - ie. if its sorted it only has to look down the first section rather than the whole list each time ?

Comment: I guess there are situations where the nearest match is preferable to no match at all.  I'm just guessing that it might relate to the way the function was originally designed in the early years.  All I can do is guess at the original intent.  I really don't know.